# ls cannot access file but it has all rights

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote script to count files that have name matching mask

```
file="/home/user1/tst_dir/NetworkActivity_5851_8_09-04-2016.done"
extension="${file##*.}"
if [ $extension = 'done' ]; then
  files="${file#*_}"
  files="${files#*_}"
  files="${files#*_}"
  files="${files%_*}"
  files=_"$files"_
  mask="${file/done/log.gz}"
  echo "${mask/$files/_*_}"
  ls /home/user1/tst_dir/NetworkActivity_5851_*_09-04-2016.log.gz | wc -l
  ls "${mask/$files/_*_}" | wc -l
fi
```

Last command return error - No such file or directory. But prior works fine.

Here is screenshot
[image]

Comment: Quoting prevents glob expansion. Remove the quotes if you want shell metacharacters to be interpreted in the entire string, or better yet, split it up into `ls "$prefix"_*_"$suffix"` to only allow glob expansion of that field.

Comment: @thatotherguy U mean something like this ls "${mask}"/"${files}"/_*_ | wc -l

Comment: You can save your soul by switching to yyyy-mm-dd date format.

Comment: @user3378876 No. The quick&dirty fix would be `ls ${mask/$files/_*_}`

Comment: More like `"${mask/$files/_}"*_` if I'm reading this correctly (which however might not be the case).

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks it's working but why is this dirty fix?

Comment: Because not quoting the parts which should be quoted is dirty.